Are (formally) smooth morphisms of curves separable?
Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a formally smooth morphism of nonsingular, proper curves $X,Y$. Is it true that $f$ is separable in the sense that $K(X)/K(Y)$ is a separable field extension?
I am asking, because we know that formally smooth morphisms and separable morphisms both induce the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to f^* \Omega_Y \to \Omega_X \to \Omega_{X/Y} \to 0.
$$
So, I am guessing there is some kind of connection / relation going on.

Since formally smooth + locally of finite presentation is equivalent to smooth (ref) and (locally) finite type is (locally) finite presentation over a locally noetherian base (ref), then as $X$ is finite type over $k$ by the properness assumption, $f$ is in fact smooth. As smoothness is preserved by base change, we see that the map on fraction fields $K(Y)\to K(X)$ is smooth, which means $K(X)$ must be a finite separable extension of $K(Y)$.
